# Using local variable within case statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, local-variables

I am trying to determine if any columns in `@pi_included_columns` is a LOB. The query below will work if I do not use the local variable (`@included_columns`). However if I just use a

```
PRINT @included_columns
```

and plug the same results into where the `@included_columns` variable is in the case statement, it will work. Why would the variable not be accepted in the `WHERE` clause?

I think it may work with Dynamic SQL but I've never used Dynamic and not sure where to start.

```
DECLARE           @offline_flag CHAR(1),-- = 'N',
                  @pi_table_name varchar(128) = 'ngkbm_default_values_',
                  @pi_included_columns varchar(1000) = ' table_name, field_name, set_value , sql_count, sql_insert, sql_update',
                  @included_columns varchar(1000),
                  @new_variable varchar(1000)




SET @included_columns = replace(@pi_included_columns,',',', ')
SET @included_columns = replace(@included_columns,'  ',' ');

SELECT @new_variable = '(''' + REPLACE(REPLACE(@included_columns , ' ' , ''), ',' , ''',''') + ''')'

SELECT @offline_flag =
       CASE 
          WHEN EXISTS (
             SELECT 1 FROM information_schema.columns 
                           WHERE (TABLE_NAME = @pi_table_name
                                   AND COLUMN_NAME IN (@new_variable)
                                   AND (data_type IN ('TEXT','NTEXT','IMAGE' ,'XML', 'VARBINARY')
                                   OR (data_type = 'VARCHAR' AND character_maximum_length = -1)
                                   OR (data_type = 'NVARCHAR' AND character_maximum_length = -1))
          )) 
          THEN 'Y' 
          ELSE 'N' 
       END
print @new_variable       
Print @offline_flag
```

Comment: If you want to do it in this way, yes you may well need dynamic SQL. Which DB engine are you using - is it SQL Server? Please add the tag for it so we can give the most appropriate answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use a comma separated string with an `in` expression to match the values inside the string.

You could create a dynamic query to use the string in that, but that means that you have to put the entire query in a string. Instead you can separate the items in the string into a set, for example a table variable:

```
declare @pos int
declare @new_variable table(name varchar(100))

set @pos = charindex(',', @pi_included_columns)
while @pos <> 0 begin
  insert into @new_variable values (ltrim(rtrim(substring(@pi_included_columns, 1, @pos - 1))))
  set @pi_included_columns = substring(@pi_included_columns, @pos + 1, len(@pi_included_columns) - @pos)
  set @pos = charindex(',', @pi_included_columns)
end
insert into @new_variable values (ltrim(rtrim(@pi_included_columns)))
```

Now you can use `@new_variable` with the `in` operator like this:

```
and COLUMN_NAME in (select name from @new_variable)
```